# How to turn off asynchronous image upload for dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm using `dropzone.js` to upload multiple images:

```
$('#dropzone_contract_images').dropzone({
    paramName: 'image',
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*'
});
```

But the problem is that when a user selects various images to upload, `dropzone.js` sends all requests at the same time, so my server (that has only one processor) sometimes responses with `503` code.

[image]

Is there any way to turn off asynchronous image upload `dropzone.js` in order to make it upload images one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading [the documentation on their homepage](http://www.dropzonejs.com/), you need to set two options in your configuration:

```
autoProcessQueue: true
parallelUploads: 1
```