# why the list<> is not populating in this code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, dropzone.js

i'm trying to populate files paths in list of strings `List<string> img = new List<string>();` when there are files posted by client using **dropzone js**
there's no exceptions the files uploaded but the list wont populate, Any idea to solve this issue ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var httpRequest = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
    HttpFileCollection uploadFiles = httpRequest.Files;
    List<string> img = new List<string>();

    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < uploadFiles.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile postedFile = uploadFiles[i];
                int fileSizeInBytes = postedFile.ContentLength;
                string fileName = postedFile.FileName;// Request.Headers["X-File-Name"];
                string fileExtension = "";

                fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                string savedFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtension;
                string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/img/items/");
                string filename = path + savedFileName;
                postedFile.SaveAs(filename);
                img.Add(filename);
            }
            itm.img1 = img[0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `img.Count` after running the code?  How do you know it won't populate?  Do you get an exception?  More information required.

Comment: @LukePark ok i will edit my question

Comment: @LukePark `img.Count` is 0 after running this code

Comment: What is httpRequest.Files.Count ?

Comment: @ZivWeissman when page loaded `httpRequest.Files.Count` is 0 but after  the the user post files it will increase as much as the posted files

Comment: Can you confirm that this ever happens?  It's not populating because the for loop never executes.

Comment: @LukePark yes i can confirm, the files are uploading to the directory that defined in the for loop declaration

Comment: Strange, could be related to async? try turning off async upload - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646800/how-to-turn-off-asynchronous-image-upload-for-dropzone-js

Comment: see the repo I posted. Get their demo running first. If your code is running to save the files from that loop, it doesn't seem possible to have img be empty (assuming you mean the /img/items folder has files showing up in it). Also your code doesn't show what itm is, and why are you only saving the first item in img[0] to itm?

Comment: @AdamTuliper-MSFT thank you m8 my problem get solved

Comment: Please post your resolution so others can see

Answer (score 0):

I ran their project from

https://github.com/venkatbaggu/dropzonefileupload

The js in the page (as per their demo) is

```
 //File Upload response from the server
        Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
            maxFiles: 2,
            url: "WebFormDropzoneDemo.aspx",
            init: function () {
                this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (data) {
                    var res = eval('(' + data.xhr.responseText + ')');
                });
                this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
                    // Create the remove button
                    var removeButton = Dropzone.createElement("Remove file");
                    // Capture the Dropzone instance as closure.
                    var _this = this;
                    // Listen to the click event
                    removeButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                        // Make sure the button click doesn't submit the form:
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        // Remove the file preview.
                        _this.removeFile(file);
                        // If you want to the delete the file on the server as well,
                        // you can do the AJAX request here.
                    });
                    // Add the button to the file preview element.
                    file.previewElement.appendChild(removeButton);
                });
            }
        };
```

This populates Request.Files just fine.

```
public partial class WebFormDropzoneDemo : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                SaveUploadedFile(Request.Files);
            }
        }


        public void SaveUploadedFile(HttpFileCollection httpFileCollection)
        {
            bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;
            string fName = "";
            foreach (string fileName in httpFileCollection)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = httpFileCollection.Get(fileName);
                //Save file content goes here
                fName = file.FileName;
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {

                    var originalDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(string.Format("{0}Images\\WallImages", Server.MapPath(@"\")));

                    string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "imagepath");

                    var fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);


                    bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString);

                    if (!isExists)
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

                    var path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString, file.FileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);

                }

            }

            //if (isSavedSuccessfully)
            //{
            //    return Json(new { Message = fName });
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    return Json(new { Message = "Error in saving file" });
            //}
        }

    }
```